# c++ Recursion Function works correctly but starts index at 0. Need it to start at 1

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

Problem is that index is starting at 0, how do I rewrite this to start at 1.

This function is using recursion

Linked List Array:

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 42 -> 10 -> NULL

Input: getPosition(head,42);

Outputs: 9

What I want:

Output: 10

```
template <class T>
int getPosition(Node<T>* head, T element) {
    //check for null
    if (head == NULL){
      return -1;
    }
    //continue if not null
    else{
      //if current elemnt does not equal wanted element
      if(head-> data != element){
        //temp var to iterate through using recursion
        int temp = getPosition(head -> next,element);
          //if temp is not equal to element, add 1 to temp
          if (temp!= -1){
              return temp+1;
          }
          //return -1 to keep loop going
          else{
              return -1;
          }
      }
      //if element found, return 0
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `return 0` to `return 1`?

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?

Comment: What a life Saver @Nate Eldredge, This was the last thing I needed in my program. Thank you so much.

Comment: I know the answer is given but I still I second the advice of using a debugger. When you do so start with a simpler example of 3 nodes. Learning to debug (which involves stepping through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables and flow) is an essential skill for programming.

Comment: Especially with recursion, it can be helpful to check simpler cases before the more complex ones. That is, verify the base case first (i.e. `getPosition(head,1)`). Once you see that return `0` instead of `1`, you have a relatively simple bit of debugging. Stepping line-by-line through the code with a debugger should reveal that the `0` comes from the line described as `//if element found, return 0`. A strange desire since you want the base case to return `1` if the element is found...